# Understanding Method Calling

Tags: java, class, methods

I found some code online to make my own little project as I want to learn Java on my spare time, I found some broken code and tried fixing it myself to the best of my ability, but now I got stuck.
The error I'm receiving is:

```
TempProg.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
    Temperature tempConv = new Temperature();
    ^
  symbol:   class Temperature
  location: class TempProg
TempProg.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
    Temperature tempConv = new Temperature();
                               ^
  symbol:   class Temperature
  location: class TempProg
2 errors



import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempProg {


public double currentTemp;
public double TempF;
public double TempK;
public double newTemp;


public TempProg(double startCurrentTemp, double startTempF, double startTempK, double startnewTemp) 
{
    currentTemp = startCurrentTemp;
    TempF = startTempF;
    TempK = startTempK;
    newTemp = startnewTemp;
}

private double Temperature(double currentTemp) 
{
    currentTemp = 100;
    return currentTemp;
}

public double convertToF(double TempF, double currentTemp) 
{
    TempF = ((9 * currentTemp) / 5 ) + 32;
    return TempF;
}

public double convertToK(double TempK, double currentTemp) 
{
    TempK = currentTemp + 273;
    return TempK;
}

public double updateTempC(double currentTemp) 
{
    newTemp = currentTemp;
    return currentTemp;
}

public double getTemp() 
{
    return currentTemp;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Temperature tempConv = new Temperature();

int newTemp;
boolean entryValid;

final int MIN_TEMP = -273;
final int MAX_TEMP = 10000;

System.out.println("\tTemperature converter");

char selection = 'x';

while (selection != 'q') { 
    System.out.println("\n\tCurrent temperature in degrees C: " + tempConv.getTemp());
    System.out.println("\tType f to display temperature in Fahrenheit");
    System.out.println("\tType k to display temperature in Kelvin");
    System.out.println("\tType c to set a new temperature");
    System.out.println("\tType q to quit");

    selection = scan.next().charAt(0);

    switch(selection) {
        case 'f': 
            System.out.println("\n\t" +tempConv.getTemp()+ " degrees C = "+tempConv.convertToF() +" degrees F" );
            break;

        case 'k':
            System.out.println("\n\t" +tempConv.getTemp()+ " degrees C = "+tempConv.convertToK() +" degrees K" );
            break;

        case 'c':

            entryValid=false;

            while (!entryValid) { 
                System.out.print("\n\tPlease enter a new temperature: ");
                newTemp = scan.nextInt();

                if (newTemp < MIN_TEMP || newTemp > MAX_TEMP) {
                    System.out.println("\tPlease enter a valid temperature");
                } else {
                    entryValid=true;
                    tempConv.updateTempC(newTemp);
                }
            }

            break;

        case 'q':
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("\n\tOption " + selection + " not understood");
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: maybe its Temperature METHOD. try changing that one (in TempProg) to temperature (lowercase)

Comment: Tried that no success :/

Comment: If Temperature class is not in the same package, you have to import the class. try that.
PS: the error means that the compiler couldnt find the Temperature class.

Answer (score 0):

At line 53, you are trying to create a new `Temperature` object with the following call:

```
Temperature tempConv = new Temperature();
```

The `new` operator in Java means that you are creating a new Object of the type specified after the `new` variable.

In order to create a new instance of a new Object, you must either have that class in the same package as the code that is creating the new instance or you must import the class.

The fact that you are getting the `cannot find symbol` error means that the compiler cannot find that class so it is not in the same package and it is not imported.

Normally, the fix for this is to import the class if it has already been created and it is in some other class. If this is code you are creating, you may need to create the `Temperature` object.

Later in your code, you have the following method:

```
private double Temperature(double currentTemp) 
{
    currentTemp = 100;
    return currentTemp;
}
```

This creates a method called `Temperature`, but it does not create a `Temperature` object. This can be confusing. In Java, to avoid this confusion, method names should always start with lowerCase letters and classes should always start with UpperCase.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to create new object by using method name.
new ClassName() is used for creating the object of that class. new keyword is used with the class name not with the method name. For calling the method first you have to create the object of that class and than with the help of that object you can call the method. In your TempProg class you don't have a default constructor you should write one default constructor if you want to create obj to TempProg without setting any value for your member variable like currentTemp,.....

In your case you should do like -

```
TempProg()
{}

TempProg  tempObj = new TempProg(); //than you can create the obj of TempProg like that
if you want to use parameterized constructor than you have to do like

TempProg tempObj = new TempPRog(11.2,222,453,455); //whatever vallue you want to set for those variables

tempObj.Temperature(1122); // call the Temperature method by passing value.
```

I am just putting some value as a example in this post.